# 他を～にできない sentence structure

Tags: meaning, manga

Konnichiwa, so I was watching "berserk 97" and this quote happened:
"-援軍は？
-ない　敵の夜襲に備える為に他を手薄に出来ないそうだ"
I'm very confused about the "他を手薄に出来ない" because "手薄" is an adjective .
I overall think that I get the meaning but I didn't grasp it at 100%.
In my head it translates like :'Because they prepare for a night attack,they cannot even do insufficient things'. I know it sounds odd but I would like to have some interpretations.
Arigatou !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

手薄 refers to a state where human resources, or “hands”, put into something are scarce or insufficient. 手薄にする means to make such a change that the resulting state is 手薄.

他を手薄に出来ない in your context means they cannot (afford to) leave other spots insufficiently guarded.

Comment: ありがとうございました。 so It means that you can replace"する" with other verbs ?

Comment: @ZEa - Not necessarily. It’s used in the `[Adj. adverbial form]-する` construction. It’s no different in structure from 大きくする. You make a change and as a result something will have become large. The adverbial form of an adjective such as 大きく and 手薄に describes the would-be, post-change state, not the manner in which something is done.